Can I force a trailing slash with Expo Router?
I am having issues where an Expo app deployed in a container can't seem to refresh correctly without a trailing slash. I figure the easiest way to fix this is to just implement a trailing slash, but I am finding Expo Router to be a magic black box I do not know how to interact with.
Can anyone show me how to add a trailing slash to all routes? It seems to get trimmed off in redirects and I don't see how to force them in a drawer or tab navigation. Thank you.

I think it is better to create a custom middleware or wrapper for your navigation container that ensures each route has a trailing slash.
